# IO bufferReader vs nio Files.newBufferedReader CharsetDecoder leniency on MalformedInput

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, nio

I have a text file that contains invalid "UTF-8" charactor and this causing my app to throw `MalformedInputException`. I use `Files.newBufferedReader` to create `BufferReader`.

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(inputDirectory, fileName);
BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

And this seems to be strict on the character encoding. I did some digging and found online that we can improve the leniency by overriding `CharactorDecoder` default action by `.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)`. This seems to be fixing the issue.

Then out of curiosity I used java IO `BufferedReader` to Read the same file.

```
fr = new FileReader(file);
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

**This seems to have no issue on the invalid character and read the file without any issue.**

So I looked at the code of both `Files.newBufferedReader` and `new BufferedReader(fr)`. This is how they both implemented

**Files.newBufferedReader**:

```
public static BufferedReader newBufferedReader(Path path, Charset cs)
    throws IOException
{
    //onMalformedInput is not overridden. Thus strict decoding
    CharsetDecoder decoder = cs.newDecoder();

    //Look at how the InputStreadReader created. The decoder being passed
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(newInputStream(path), decoder);

    return new BufferedReader(reader);
}
```

**IO BuffereReader**

```
//Creating File Reader
 FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

 --------------------------------------------------------------------
//File Reader constructor
public FileReader(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //Calls it's supper constructor InputStreamReader
    super(new FileInputStream(file));
}

-----------------------------------------------------------
//InputStreamReader Constructor
public InputStreamReader(InputStream in) {
    super(in);
    try {
        //This where I don't understand
        sd = StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(in, this, (String)null); // ## check lock object
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}
```

As you can see they both uses `StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader`. I know why `Files.newBufferedReader` has strict decoder. But I am trying to understand where in IO `BufferredReader`, it's defined to do lenient decoding.

Would really appreciate if some can help me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The lenient decoding should actually be done by `FileReader`. I can't find any part of the documentation that specifies this, but digging into its code it uses `onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)` too. I'm not sure if it can be trusted to be the same way in all JDK implementations though.